# ActiveRecord :inverse_of does not work on has_many :through on the join model on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I can't get `inverse_of` to work on join models on creation. I'm not sure if this is a bug or just not implemented as such.  I have the following models:

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_challenges
  has_many :group_challenges, :inverse_of => :challenge

  attr_accessor :contact_ids
end

class GroupChallenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :challenge, :inverse_of => :group_challenges
  belongs_to :group, :inverse_of => :group_challenges

  before_save :check_challenge

  def check_challenge
    Rails.logger.debug("challenge.contact_ids: #{challenge.contact_ids}")
  end
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :challenges, :through => :group_challenges
  has_many :group_challenges, :inverse_of => :group
end
```

`contact_ids` is a virtual attribute of my `challenge`, and I'd like to access these in the `group_challenges` model when that association is created.  I can't get it to work.  Here's an example:

```
challenge = Challenge.new :groups => Group.all, :contact_ids => [1,2,3]
# log output => challenge.contact_ids: []
```

However `inverse_of` does work when the models are reloaded

```
challenge.reload
challenge.group_challenges.first.challenge.contact_ids
# log output => challenge.contact_ids: [1,2,3]
```

Does anyone know if this is just a design limitation of inverse_of or rather a bug in the implementation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per the [active record api](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods) 3.2.1: "Currently :inverse_of supports has_one and has_many (**but not the :through variants**) associations. It also supplies inverse support for belongs_to associations where the inverse is a has_one and it’s not a polymorphic."

Comment: oh good one, ya I never noticed that documentation.  Too bad, it would be so handy!!