# Rails updating model through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I have the following two models:

```
class Process < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :activities, inverse_of: :artifact, dependent: :destroy
 attr_accessible :name, :activities_attributes
 def update_status!
   if self.activities.all? {|a| a.completed? }
     self.status = 'completed'
   elsif self.activities.any? {|a| a.completed? }
     self.status = 'in_progress'
   else
     self.status = 'not_started'
   end

   save!
 end
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :process, inverse_of: :activities
    attr_accessible :name,:completed_date
    scope :completed, where("completed_date is not null")
end
```

Then in my Controller:

```
 @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
 @activity.completed_date = Time.now
 @activity.process.update_status!
```

If I put a debugger directly after this line, and print out @activity.completed it returns true, however @artifact.status is still "not_started" (assume no other activities).

However, if I add the following line before the update:

```
 @activity.process.activities[@activity.process.activities.index(@activity)] = @activity
```

The status is updated correctly.

Why doesn't the change to @activity propagate into process.activities? And how can I make it propagate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't this `inverse_of` works with has_many through.  See this article: [ActiveRecord :inverse_of does not work on has_many :through on the join model on create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436173/activerecord-inverse-of-does-not-work-on-has-many-through-on-the-join-model-on)

Here is the relevant blurb from the [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html):

> There are a few limitations to inverse_of support:
>
> They do not work with :through associations. They do not work with
>   :polymorphic associations. They do not work with :as associations. For
>   belongs_to associations, has_many inverse associations are ignored.

Comment: 'for belongs_to associations, has_many inverse associations are ignored' that was it then. Thanks, and sorry for screwing up your score ;)