# Establishing A Has One Through vs Has Many Through With Unsaved Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many-through, has-one-through

I have written a gem that allows Google Spreadsheets to be transformed into Rails models. The sequence of this process involves creating all the models, then hooking up their associations, then saving all the models. It supports all the types of association available, and in every case bar one, creating the models, establishing associations, then saving the models works correctly. The exception is as follows:

I have a simple `has_one, through` association (attribute access omitted for brevity) :

```
class Left < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :middles, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :rights, through: :middles
end

class Right < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_one :middle, dependent: :destroy
   has_one :left, through: :middle
end

class Middle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :left
  belongs_to :right
end
```

I'm finding some inconsistent behaviour depending on which side the assignment of the association is made:

Assigning right to left:

```
left = Left.new
right = Right.new
left.rights << right
left.middles #[]
right.middle #nil
left.save!
left.middles # <Middle theme_id: 1, archive_resource_id: 1 >
```

Assigning right to left:

```
left = Left.new
right = Right.new
right.left = left
left.middles #[]
right.middle <Middle theme_id: nil, archive_resource_id: nil >
right.save!
right.middle # <Middle theme_id: nil, archive_resource_id: 1 >
```

**This behaviour seems very inconsistent. Why is this? Why does this work one way and not the other? Is there any way to establish this relationship with both records unsaved?**

I appreciate that the obvious solution is to save everything before setting up the relationships, but as explained above, I need the models to be unsaved *when the associations are established*, and in every other type of association, there is no problem in this regard.

Comment: If ```Left``` and ```Right``` models also inherited from ```ActiveRecord::Base```?
Also why ```Left``` model ```has_many :right``` ? Maybe it should be ```has_many :rightS``` or ```has_one :right```?

Comment: @freemanoid Sorry, yes they are (amended in question).

Comment: ```has_many :middleS``` and ```has_many :rightS```

Comment: @freemanoid Another typo I'm afraid. It's a `has-many through:` vs a `has_one through:`

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about the relationships. If your `Left` model has a `has_many` relationship with a bunch of `Right` objects, and the `Right` objects have a `has_one` relationship with a single `Left` object, why do you need the intermediary `Middle` model? From what it looks like, you have a "one-to-many", not a "many-to-many".

Comment: @Teeg I need attributes on middle. I've removed anything that is superfluous to the question.

Comment: @pedr You mentioned in Anurag Abbott's answer that you're not using `build`. I've been looking in to this a fair bit, and thus far the only solution I've come up with involves using `build`. Is there a reason you don't want to / can't use that method?

Comment: @Teeg Yes. My use-case involves creating instances of each kind of model separately and then connecting them. This is for a number of reasons, partly so that the creation phase is transactional - if any creation fails I can back out of the whole process without altering the database. Basically there are three phases. 1. Create all types of object 2. Connect all objects 3. Save all objects. If I could use build then I wouldn't have needed to ask this question.

Comment: @Pedr Alright well best of luck then. I can only think of two workarounds: 1- wrap the entire operation in a transaction (`Left.transaction do ...` for example), and manually raising an active record rollback if necessary, or 2 - save the associations in non-persistent attributes (a simple array for the `has_many`, etc) until you're ready to persist, at which point you simply assign them to the appropriate active record associations as normal.

Comment: @Teeg. Thanks. Good advice. It's so frustrating as in every other case everything works perfectly. It's just this one specific kind of association where it doesn't.

Comment: @Pedr Yeah I know what you mean; I've answered two questions recently that are similar to this problem. Ultimately, I don't believe there is any good "Rails way" of handling this type of situation through the common ActiveRecord semantics, as Rails is simply not really build to accommodate this. This is obviously a semi-common problem though, and there are ways to solve it of course, I'm just not certain which approach would be considered "best practice".

Answer (score 0):

As per the Rails API docs([link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+Join+Models))-

> If you are using a belongs_to on the join model, it is a good idea to
>   set the :inverse_of option on the belongs_to, which will mean that the
>   following example works correctly (where tags is a has_many :through
>   association):

So the association set up by @Kaleidoscope is infact correct.

Comment: Maybe this is true if you are using `build`, but as outlined in the question I am not using `build`, but `new` then `save`. @Kaleidoscope's answer is not correct as he has used `inverse_of` in the the other direction: `has_one :middle, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :right`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's didn't work because you have

> has_many - has_one

relation between Left and Right instead of

> has_many - belongs_to

On the other hand

> belongs_to :left, through: :middle

isn't possible. So you should use delegate for getter and write setter method by youself, something like this

```
class Right < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :middle, dependent: :destroy
  delegate :left, to: :middle

  def left=(left)
    #logic
  end
end
```

Comment: What's wrong with using a `has_many, through` or a `has_one, through`?   Both are clearly documented.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's probably working, but not updating immediately. Try passing `true` when you call your association methods. Ex. `right.middle(true)`. This will force Rails to go back to the database to get the record instead of checking the cache, which is stale. Don't do this on new records though, as you'll blow away the associated object in memory.

To avoid having to force a reload, set `inverse_of` on your associations:

```
class Left < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :middles, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :left
   has_many :rights, through: :middles
end

class Right < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_one :middle, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :right
   has_one :left, through: :middle
end

class Middle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :left, inverse_of: :middles
  belongs_to :right, inverse_of: :middle
end
```

`inverse_of` makes a `model` aware of an associated model's relationship to itself, which allows it to be "smart" about persisting and loading associated objects.

Comment: Unfortunately, `inverse_of` isn't supported for `through` associations: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436173/activerecord-inverse-of-does-not-work-on-has-many-through-on-the-join-model-on

Comment: Err, yeah. Sorry. It was late.

Comment: No problem. Voting down so it's clear this answer is incorrect.