# Setting inverse_of on has_many :through rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The documentation implies that inverse_of will work for everything except polymorphic  associations.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses

However it appears inverse_of still doesn't work for has_many :through

e.g. every combination I have tried for inverse_of on the follow example doesn't work

```
class Event  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :users, through: :attendance
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances 
  has_many :events, through: :attendances
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
```

any ideas of this should work? and if so how I would set inverse_of in this example?

### UPDATE

e.g. of what i tried ( also tried on has_many :through)

```
class Event  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances , :inverse_of => :event
  has_many :users, through: :attendance
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances , :inverse_of => :user
  has_many :events, through: :attendances
end
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event, :inverse_of => :attendances
  belongs_to :user,  :inverse_of => :attendances
end
```

also tried

```
class Event  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances  
  has_many :users, through: :attendance , :inverse_of => :events
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances 
  has_many :events, through: :attendances ,:inverse_of => :users
end
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Can you show us the examples you tried (and the errors you got)?

Comment: no error just doesn't work i.e loading an event and then loading a user and getting the event via the attednance.event are not same object even objects which is what inverse_of should do so if you make changes that are not persisted the objects are different

Comment: Hi check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436173/activerecord-inverse-of-does-not-work-on-has-many-through-on-the-join-model-on

Comment: thought this was updated in rails 4.1 (look at documentation seems like it was)

Answer (score 21):

I had the same question in rails 4.1.6 (that's how I stumbled upon this question).

It took a bit of trial and error (and server restarts), but the following works for me:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_users
  has_many :companies, through: :company_users
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_users
  has_many :users, through: :company_users
end

class CompanyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :company_users
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :company_users
end
```

**For clarity:**

[image: Schema]

**Example:**

```
user = User.last
company = user.companies.build( ... )
company.save
# ...
# SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "public"."company_users" ("company_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["company_id", 4], ["created_at", "2014-10-03 03:40:58.836975"], ["updated_at", "2014-10-03 03:40:58.836975"], ["user_id", 1]]
(1.6ms)  COMMIT
CompanyUser.last
<CompanyUser:0x00000020339710> {
        :id => 4,
:company_id => 4,
   :user_id => 1,
:created_at => Thu, 02 Oct 2014 20:40:58 PDT -07:00,
:updated_at => Thu, 02 Oct 2014 20:40:58 PDT -07:00
}
```

So basically I only set the inverse_of in the join model

Comment: Great answer! Basically add  `:inverse_of` only to where you specify `:class_name` or `:foreign_key` options. This is mentioned in rubocop and other docs. Rails can imply `inverse_of` in other places.

Comment: An update for Rails 6 – I had to specify the `inverse_of` on all of the associations: the `has_many`, the `has_many through`, and the `belongs_to` in the joining model.

Answer (score 2):

The [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations) say inverse_of is not supported when using :through. Specifically:

---

There are a few limitations to inverse_of support:

- They do not work with :through associations.
- They do not work with :polymorphic associations.
- They do not work with :as associations.
- For belongs_to associations, has_many inverse associations are ignored.

---

Comment: Actually on this page http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses   it states "If you are using a belongs_to on the join model, it is a good idea to set the :inverse_of option on the belongs_to, which will mean that the following example works correctly (where tags is a has_many :through association):
...
The last line ought to save the through record (a Taggable). This will only work if the :inverse_of is set"

Answer (score 1):

The inverse_of does automatically get set ever since Rails 4.1, as long as you don't use class_name or foreign_key.  In the last part of this video about setting up Rails 5 models there's an example of how a has_many relationship behaves without, and then with the inverse_of.  An RSpec test is written to first show that object_ids are different, and then after adding inverse_of they end up to be the same:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sfufoY59Ek&feature=youtu.be&t=42m54s

Answer (score 0):

If you just use through assocation, do

```
class Event  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :users, through: :attendances ## there must be  plural too
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances 
  has_many :events, through: :attendances
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
```

Then `Event` and `User` will search each other by `Attendance` model(by `event_id` and `user_id` in `attendances` table in db). To see the detail, see [rails assocation explian](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

If you want to use `inverse_of` assocation, this means there relation will binding by themself instead the third party. First you can do:

```
class Event  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :users, :inverse_of => :events
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances 
  has_many :events, :inverse_of => :users
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
```

Then you need to change your migration file like this:

```
creata_table :events do |t|
  ....
  t.string, :user_id
end

creata_table :users do |t|
  ....
  t.string, :event_id
end
```

Like `@event.users` will search users by `user_id` in User model directly but not through Attendance model.

BTW, `through` can not used with `inverse_of` together, Rails guide has declear it.