# Using inverse_of on a has_many :through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'll start off with my test, to show the desired functionality:

```
    item = LineItem.new
    order = Order.new
    OrderLineItem.new(order: order, line_item: item)

    related_order = item.orders.first
    expect(related_order).to eq order
```

which evaluates to:

```
 expected: #<Order ....>
      got: nil
```

---

The 3 models above are related as follows:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_line_items, as: :line_item, inverse_of: :line_item

  has_many :orders,
           through: :order_line_items,
           source: :order,
           inverse_of: :line_items
end


class OrderLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :order_line_items
  belongs_to :line_item,
             polymorphic: true, inverse_of: :order_line_items
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items,
           through: :order_line_items,
           source: :line_item,
           inverse_of: :orders

  has_many :order_line_items, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :order

end
```

I can make this all work by saving everything and calling `item.reload` before my expect line. But isn't `inverse_of` supposed to hook all this up? 
Maybe I'm expecting too much of `inverse_of` with pre-saved objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `inverse_of` doesn't work with `has_many :through`

See the "Bidirectional associations" section of the ActiveRecords associations docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.

> There are limitations to :inverse_of support:
>
> - does not work with :through associations.
> - does not work with :polymorphic associations.
> - for belongs_to associations has_many inverse associations are ignored.

See also: [ActiveRecord :inverse_of does not work on has_many :through on the join model on create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436173/activerecord-inverse-of-does-not-work-on-has-many-through-on-the-join-model-on)